# python request cookies

Tags: python, request, lxml

Хочу отправить cookie по адресу:
`https://store.steampowered.com/app/745960/A_Sky_Full_of_Stars/`

Код:

```
cookies = dict(mature_content = 1)
r = requests.get(url, cookies)
```

Первоначально на этой странице требуется проверка возраста. После нажатия на кнопку грузится уже основная страница, а куки содержат `mature_content = 1`.

Я отправляю cookie в надежде, что сразу загрузится основная страница, а не страница с проверкой возраста, но грузится именно страница с проверкой возраста.

Что я делаю не так? С cookie первый раз работаю.

Comment: Вы неправильно передаёте cookies, [читайте документацию](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так должно работать

```
import requests
url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/app/745960/A_Sky_Full_of_Stars/'
cookies = dict(mature_content = '1')
r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: спасибо, работает